# Do we use volumes of both solutions if they have different densities to find cocentration of ions

Tags: stoichiometry

So essentially lets say I am given a mixture of  **hexane**, **water** and **nickel** **chloride**(masses also given) in a beaker, and am asked to find the concentration of the chloride ions in the aqueous layer of the mixture.

Now, I know what we should first do is find the mols of NiCl2(using the given mass)
**mass of NiCl2/molar mass of NiCl2**

However, knowing that hexane is less dense than water, hexane will not "mix" and instead float on top of the nickel chloride solution (Sorry for my poor/incorrect terminology!).

So my question here is, when we find the concentration using c=m/v, do we include the volume of the hexane as well? Or only the volume of the water in which the nickel has dissolved in. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your terminology is fine (indeed, hexane will float on top), but your way of thinking is not. Why on Earth would you include the volume of hexane? You could just as well add the volume of **air** in the room. After all, air is much like hexane: it also kinda "floats" on top of solution and doesn't mix with it.

Comment: I guess I assumed we had to include hexane since both were liquids(and got that mixed up with aqueous since it asks for concentration in the aqueous layer, my bad!). But your explaination has cleared my confusion. Thank you!